# Why does `python -c 'print('howdy')'` produce an error (in zsh), but `python -c 'print("howdy")'` does not?

Tags: zsh, double-quotes, single-quotes

When, in `zsh`, I execute `python -c 'print('howdy')'` from the command line, it produces the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'howdy' is not defined
```

However, this `python -c 'print("howdy")'` does not, and instead produces the output expected by me, namely, `howdy` (as a string) is sent to `stdout`?

I thought python was agnostic on single or double quotes

Comment: Python doesn't mind which quote character you are using, but in your first example you have provided `print(` and `)` in quotes.

Comment: In the first version you're using the same kind of quotes to mean two different things.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the inner quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zsh is first parsing the command, following its own rules on quotes. To zsh, the command `python -c 'print('howdy')'` looks something like the following:

- We're calling the program `python`
- The first argument is `-c`
- The second argument is `'print('` enclosed in quotes, followed by `howdy`, followed by `')'` enclosed in quotes.

Zsh is "expanding" this second argument to `'print(howdy)'`. If you run this command in python you get the error you describe.

Comment: The correct term is quote removal. `'print('howdy')'` is a single word, two parts of which are contained in single quotes. Once the shell is done processing the command line, the command name is identified as `python`, and two words `-c` and `print(howdy)` are identified as the arguments to the command.